# what is the difference between PHP regex and javascript regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

i am working in regex my regex is `/\[([^]\s]+).([^]]+)\]/g` this  works great in PHP for `[http://sdgdssd.com fghdfhdhhd]`
but when i use this regex for javascript it do not match with this input string

my input is `[http://sdgdssd.com fghdfhdhhd]`

Comment: You sure your statement is correct? I'd imagine `/\[([^]\s]+).([^]]+)\]/g` might work in JS but not PHP; PHP has different modifiers than JS. `g` is not a PHP modifier.

Comment: this works on PHP you can check it by execute on https://regex101.com

Comment: regex101 isn't a PHP interpretor. That is just a regex tester. https://eval.in/481587 See http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php The regex is valid but it won't work in PHP with that modifier. The PHP functions are global already or there is a function for it to be global (preg_match_all vs. preg_match)..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In JavaScript regex, you must **always** escape the `]` inside a character class:

```
\[([^\]\s]+).([^\]]+)\]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY4lR7/1)

JS parsed `[^]` as *any character including a newline in your regex, and the final character class `]` symbol as a literal `]`.

In this regard, *JS regex engine deviates from the [POSIX standard](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)* where *smart placement* is used to match `[` and `]` symbols with bracketed expressions like `[^][]`.

> The `]` character is treated as a literal character if it is the first character after `^`: `[^]abc]`.

In [JS and Ruby](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special), that is not working like that:

> You can include an unescaped closing bracket by placing it right after the opening bracket, or right after the negating caret. `[]x]` matches a closing bracket or an `x`. `[^]x]` matches any character that is not a closing bracket or an `x`. This does not work in JavaScript, which treats `[]` as an empty character class that always fails to match, and `[^]` as a negated empty character class that matches any single character. Ruby treats empty character classes as an error. So **both JavaScript and Ruby require closing brackets to be escaped with a backslash to include them as literals in a character class**.

**Related:**

- `(?1)` [regex subroutine](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) used to shorten a PCRE pattern conversion - [REGEX from PHP to JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275590)

Comment: That's strange the the `]` doesn't need to be escaped in PCRE. I've always escaped just out of instinct because I thought it would choke on that if not.

Comment: @chris85: I just edited the answer since I double checked and found `[` does not need to be escaped inside a character class in JS.

Comment: Added some more explanations related to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add this little fact about translating PHP `preg_replace` Regex in JavaScript `.replace` Regex :

```
<?php preg_replace("/([^0-9\,\.\-])/i";"";"-1 220 025.47 $"); ?>
Result : "-1220025.47"
```

with PHP, you have to use the quotes `"..."` around the Regex, a point comma to separate the Regex with the replacement and the brackets are used as a repetition research (witch do not mean the same thing at all.

```
<script>"-1 220 025.47 $".replace(/[^0-9\,\.\-]/ig,"") </script>
Result : "-1220025.47"
```

With JavaScript, no quotes around the Regex, a comma to separate Regex with the replacement and you have to use `/g` option in order to say multiple research in addition of the `/i` option (that's why `/ig`).

I hope this will be usefull to someone !
Note that the `"\,"` may be suppressed in case of `"1,000.00 $"` (English ?) kind of number :

```
<script>"-1,220,025.47 $".replace(/[^0-9\.\-]/ig,"")</script>
<?php preg_replace("/([^0-9\.\-])/i";"";"-1,220,025.47 $"); ?>
Result : "-1220025.47"
```