# Regex match expression works in php but not with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, match

I have this string:

**$str = "35x35";**

The regex function works fine in php, returns true:

```
preg_match('/^\d*(x|X){1}\d*$/',trim($str))
```

But when I transfer this function to javascript it doesn't work and it returns null:

```
$str.trim().match('/^\d*(x|X){1}\d*$/');
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You can explore this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134741/what-is-the-difference-between-php-regex-and-javascript-regex

Comment: `/^\d+x\d+$/i.test(string)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove those `'`. In Javascript, regex literals are `/` not `'`.

```js
const $str = "35x35";

console.log($str.trim().match(/^\d*(x|X){1}\d*$/));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
var reg = /^\d*(x|X){1}\d*$/;
var isMatch = reg.test('35x35'); // return true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omit `{1}` from your regex and if you don't use the capturing group `(x|X)` you could write that as `[xX]` or just x with the case insensitive flag `/i`.

Your regex could look like `\d+x\d+$` using the and if your want to return a boolean you can use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Note that you don't use the single quotes for `let pattern` and if you use `\d*` that would match zero or more digits and would also match a single `x`.

```js
let str = "35x35";
let pattern = /^\d+x\d+$/i;
console.log(pattern.test(str));
```

Or use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to retrieve the matches.

```js
let str = "35x35";
let pattern = /^\d+x\d+$/i;
console.log(str.match(pattern)[0]);
```