# How to properly write a form in Laravel or other frameworks?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, forms, validation

I am quite new to Laravel, but I have already read about [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) and [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/). I feel these methods to be quite cumbersome because the validation takes place at different levels:

- Validation on the Database (foreign key constraint, column types)
- Validation on the Model (through the `set...Attribute` methods)
- Validation on the Request trait
- Validation on the frontend (e.g. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#supported-elements))

For example, I would like to write a form with a country selector. My database have a `VARCHAR(2)` column to receive the country code. I have to write the `setCountryAttribute` method on my Model to validate the value against the accepted countries. Then I have to write a Form Request `php artisan make:request StoreCustomerPost` which is a partial copy paste of the  `setCountryAttribute` code. Eventually I have to write a bit of JavaScript to do the validation on the client side.

Doing this for every field of every form of a big application is just not acceptable.

What I am looking for is a more optimized solution which involves meta-programming. For instance, I may use a toolbox factory that can generate all the fronend HTML including the JS validation code, the Request validation, and the Model validation.

Let's take the example of a `age` form field. I think it could be defined as follow:

```
"age": {
    "type": "textfield",
    "name": "age",
    "validation": {
        "type": "integer"        
        "pattern": "/\d{1,2}|1\d{2}/",
        "minValue": 0,
        "maxValue": 122,
    },
    "view": {
        "template": "form.fields.textfield",    
        "placeholder": "Age",
        "size": "10em",
        "title": "Age",
        "validation": true
    }
}
```

This information is enough to dynamically generate:

- Model Validation `setAgeAttribute` perhaps through a more generic `setAttribute` trait method.
- Request Validator attached to my controller
- Frontend code.

So in my controller I am expecting something like:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $form = Form::fill(Customer::find($id))
        ->field('age');
        ->field('firstname');
        ->field('lastname');

    return view('customers.edit', ['form' => $form->toBlade()]);
}
```

### Is there a solution close enough to this proposal?

Comment: This is interesting and common problem. I am annoying too that each library has own validation code. You can create common class that validates this object and use it in js, models and so on. for example: user class has property $validations = ... and method validate. You can pass this common object to all classes and generate the javascript code based on them. I dont know if there is library for js validation exacly. You can create your own or use existing one but maybe adapt your rules to match the js library rules structure

Comment: Is this it? https://github.com/kristijanhusak/laravel-form-builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts first:

- not all PHP functions used in validation have a counterpart in Javascript and vica versa. [Not even regex behaves the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134741/what-is-the-difference-between-php-regex-and-javascript-regex) in both languages. Check regex101 for subtle differences.
- You can just use xhr (ajax) calls to the laravel validation, however I agree it is best to prevent unnecessary calls to the server with client validation.
- we could make our own library that tries to reflect the current possibilities of Laravel validation for js.
- There is an upcoming technique called [webassembly which might make it possible to use PHP in the browser](https://github.com/oraoto/pib) and build a more compatible frontend validation this way. Of course this frontend language is still bound to the limitations of the browser's API.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am looking for is a more optimized solution which involves meta-programming. For instance, I may use a toolbox factory that can generate all the fronend HTML including the JS validation code, the Request validation, and the Model validation.

I feel your pain :-) Although the question is a bit broad because its not easy to answer if there is *somewhere* such a tool you describe. At least I can say, I never saw or heard of one for Laravel.

Before I used Laravel I worked on a big project with MeteorJS and they have the awesome [Collection 2 package](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2), which I miss deeply in Laravel. But I think its easier to handle if you have just have to deal with one language for backend and frontend than with two.

So I would say you have to do it all by yourself, but looking forward with you if somebody comes up with some hidden gem :-)