# REGEX from PHP to JS

Tags: regex

Could you suggest how to correct this expression

```
(^([0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(?:,\s*(?1))*$)
```

for use with javascript, so that it gives the true when the date formats are `yyyy-mm-yy` and when the dates are listed separated by commas if there are several of them?

```
Expected result:
2017-03-25, 2017-03-27, 2017-03-28 true
2017-03-25 true
```

Comment: Maybe like so: `^(([0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(,\s)?)+)$`

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support recursive regexp. You should do it using a quantifier instead.

Comment: This doesn't work as it should, result 
2017-03-25, 2017-03-27, 2017-03-28 false ( must be true) 
2017-03-25 true

Comment: `(?1)` stands for the whole Group  1 pattern. So, the right answer is `^[0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:,\s*[0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))*$`, https://regex101.com/r/FomX9Q/1. Actually, your PHP regex has a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP regex contains a bug, namely, the Group 1 parentheses are wrapping the whole pattern while the recursed part should only be `([0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`.

So, in order to fix the PHP pattern, you need to remove the outer parentheses:

```
^([0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(?:,\s*(?1))*$
```

Since the `(?1)` [regex subroutine](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) recurses the Group 1 pattern, all you need is to *repeat* the pattrn in a JS regex:

```
^[0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:,\s*[0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FomX9Q/1).

In JS code, do not write it as a regex literal, create it dynamically for easier maintenance:

```js
const date_reg = `[0-9]{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`;
const reg = new RegExp(String.raw`^${date_reg}(?:,\s*${date_reg})*$`);
console.log(reg.test("2017-03-25, 2017-03-27, 2017-03-28"));
```

Comment: @FedorovDmitriy  I also linked the answer to another one that is also related to [PHP to JS regex conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134741/what-is-the-difference-between-php-regex-and-javascript-regex?noredirect=1&lq=1), just in case someone stumbles across a related problem.